# auto populate name in people picker field

Tags: jquery

I have people picker field "Manager" and want it to auto populate in new form with constant value "kumar, brishal"
How I can do it using jquery.

I am using below code, when I double click in textbox it show "kumar, brishal" but user will not like this UI. please help

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/ui-

lightness/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script  type="text/javascript" 

src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-

2014.02.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" 

src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-

2014.02.min.js"></script>
<script 

src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-

2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


 var defaultuser = "kumar, brishal";
$('input[title="Project manager"]').val(defaultuser);




});

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: just set default value by editing the column

Comment: how? we do not have option to set default value in people picket like choice field

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a placeholder attribute on the field to hold that value.  This way you do not have to have a hard default value for it.  Try this:

```
$('input[title="Project manager"]').attr("placeholder", "kumar, brishal");
```

That should do it.